# Calculate date of holiday using a factor table to add/subtract days from a specific date

Tags: mysql, sql

**[DB-Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d81f53a87e77e715660954ceca60182d)**

```
CREATE TABLE holidays (
    id int primary key,
    name VARCHAR(255), 
    calc_type VARCHAR(255),
    calc_factor VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO holidays 
(id, name, calc_type, calc_factor
)
VALUES 
("1", "Holdiay_01", "fixed", "0"),
("2", "Holdiay_02", "fixed", "0"),
("3", "Holdiay_03", "fixed", "0"),
("4", "Holdiay_04", "moveable", "10"),
("5", "Holdiay_05", "moveable", "-5");
```

The table above I want to use to calculate the `date` of a holiday in an SQL query. 
The holidays are divided in two different `calculation types`:

**fixed** = same date every year

```
(YYYY-03-01, YYYY-05-12, YYYY-08-09)
```

**moveable** = date is calculated by adding/subtracting a pre-defined amount of days (`calc_factor`) from a fixed date:

```
(YYYY-11-12) + 10, (YYYY-11-12) - 5
```

In the end the result should look like this:

```
id       name              date
1     Holiday_01         2019-03-01
2     Holiday_02         2019-05-12
3     Holiday_03         2019-08-09
4     Holiday_04         2019-11-22
5     Holiday_05         2019-11-07
```

I tried to go with something like this but could not make it work so far:

```
SELECT
id,
name,

 CASE (
  WHEN name = "Holdiay_01" THEN DATE_ADD(YEAR(CURDATE()) & MONTH(3) & DAY(1), INTERVAL calc_factor)
  WHEN name = "Holdiay_02" THEN DATE_ADD(YEAR(CURDATE()) & MONTH(5) & DAY(12), INTERVAL calc_factor)
  WHEN name = "Holdiay_03" THEN DATE_ADD(YEAR(CURDATE()) & MONTH(9) & DAY(8), INTERVAL calc_factor)
  WHEN name = "Holdiay_04" THEN DATE_ADD(YEAR(CURDATE()) & MONTH(11) & DAY(12), INTERVAL calc_factor)
  WHEN name = "Holdiay_05" THEN DATE_ADD(YEAR(CURDATE()) & MONTH(11) & DAY(12), INTERVAL calc_factor)
 ELSE NULL END ) AS date

FROM holidays;
```

How do I have to modify my query to get the expected result?

Comment: Where do the 3, 5, 9, 11, etc.  values come from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a rather perverse data model -- a row regarding a holiday but not the date.  That said, the following does what you want after fixing the holiday names:

```
SELECT id, name,
       (CASE WHEN name = 'Holiday_01' THEN DATE_ADD(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-03-01'), INTERVAL calc_factor DAY)
             WHEN name = 'Holiday_02' THEN DATE_ADD(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-05-12'), INTERVAL calc_factor DAY)
             WHEN name = 'Holiday_03' THEN DATE_ADD(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-09-08'), INTERVAL calc_factor DAY)
             WHEN name = 'Holiday_04' THEN DATE_ADD(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-11-12'), INTERVAL calc_factor DAY)
             WHEN name = 'Holiday_05' THEN DATE_ADD(CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()), '-11-12'), INTERVAL calc_factor DAY)
        END) as date
FROM holidays;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=43df060e30855556c28b79602868a3db) is the corresponding db<>fiddle.

Some issues with your code apart from the misspelt names:

- `&` is a bitwise `AND` operator.  You appear to want to construct a date, so `CONCAT()` is appropriate.
- `INTERVAL` requires a time unit.
- `MONTH()` and `DAY()` are functions that extract those components from a date.  An argument such as "3" is converted to a date -- and because it is not a date, the returned value is `NULL`.
- As a matter of simplification, `ELSE NULL` is superfluous, because `CASE` expressions return `NULL` if no conditions match.

Comment: Actually, the idea is to calculate the date and the weekday of a holiday automatically based on the current year and store this information in a table. Not sure if this is the correct way to go in mySQL for this. I might be too muched influenced by the way I do it in Excel. Maybe the better approach is to just create a table in which I pre-define all dates of holidays for a couple of years.

Comment: Extended DB-Fiddle for my describe approach in the comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c911fccadd0c355f917f07c2770b6c02

Answer (score 2):

MySQL has the CONCAT() function, which allows you to concatenate two or more strings. The function actually allows for one or more arguments, but its main use is to concatenate two or more strings.

> Following is your answer:

```
SELECT
id,
name,

CASE 
 WHEN name = 'Holdiay_01' THEN DATE_ADD((CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-03-01')), 
     INTERVAL (calc_factor) DAY)
 WHEN name = 'Holdiay_02' THEN DATE_ADD((CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-05-12')), 
     INTERVAL (calc_factor) DAY)
 WHEN name = 'Holdiay_03' THEN DATE_ADD((CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-08-09')), 
     INTERVAL (calc_factor) DAY)
 WHEN name = 'Holdiay_04' THEN DATE_ADD((CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-11-12')), 
     INTERVAL (calc_factor) DAY)
 WHEN name = 'Holdiay_05' THEN DATE_ADD((CONCAT(YEAR(CURDATE()),'-11-12')), 
     INTERVAL (calc_factor) DAY)
 ELSE NULL END AS date

 FROM holidays;
```

> Also check in DB Fiddle:

[**DB-Fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=85f01d4eac817715154e7f68c779844c)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but when I runt it here I get NULL for the dates: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ed8b9f3029c265b5d0d822523a217620

Comment: Hii michi,  please check given DB-Fiddle link given by me. it's working fine.

Comment: @Michi, you have line breaks in your date in dbfiddle.